# I have to click multiple times before the dialog box closes, or performs the next action...How do I fix this?

Tags: c#

Here is my C# code:

```
private void StudentReg_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close this window?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes) 
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `Application.Exit();`? Just do nothing and let the form close itself

Comment: Dmitry, first, thanks for editing my code :) .I am new to coding, so not sure if that is a  good practice. I will try it though.

Comment: In other words, all you need is `if (dialog == DialogResult.No) e.Cancel = true;`

Comment: it sort of depends on if your goal is to completely close the application or to just let the window close while the application keeps running.  If you want the app to keep running Dmitry's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you really want `Application.Exit();`: you prompt (bold is mine)

> Do you really want to close this **window**

It is the *window* (`Form`), not the entire `Aplication` you want to close. If it's your case, you can just *do nothing* and let the form (window) close itself:

```
private void StudentReg_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel closing (i.e. do NOT close the form) if and only if user's chosen "No".
    // Do nothing (i.e. do not cancel) in other cases (let the form be closed)
    // So we assign true (cancel) if "No" has been pressed, false otherwise 
    e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show(
      "Do you really want to close this window?", 
      "Exit", 
       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you setup your application like if this is your main form or you have multiple you may need to just remove the event to avoid duplicate calls to it.

Remove the event handler before calling application.exit and I think your issue will be solved.

This is psuedo-code.

```
private void StudentReg_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close this window?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if(dialog == DialogResult.Yes) 
            {
                StudentReg.FormClosing -= StudentReg_FormClosing; 
                Application.Exit();
           
            }
            else if(dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

                }
        }
```